# What is the use of Group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

The following is the "printer" table which contains details about printer.

```
user=> SELECT * FROM printer ;
 code |   model   | color |  type  |   price    
------+-----------+-------+--------+------------
 1002 | ProXPress | y     | laser  | ₹20,000.00
 1003 | M1136     | y     | jet    |    ₹100.00
 1004 | Air1000   | y     | laser  |  ₹1,000.00
 1001 | ML 2161   | n     | matrix |     ₹90.00
(4 rows)
user=>
```

Now I want to find cheapest color printer. So, I tried the following way.

```
user=> SELECT min(price) from printer where color='y';
   min   
---------
 ₹100.00
(1 row)
user=>
```

It gives the expected price as output. But I want result set as code,model and price. So, I tried the following way.

```
user=> SELECT code,model,min(price) from printer where color='y';
ERROR:  column "printer.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT code,model,min(price) from printer where color='y';
user=>
```

It shows error as shown above. So, what is meant by group by clause and what is the way to achieve expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*column "printer.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate* means that columns selected that aren't in an aggregate function (MIN is an aggregate function) must be in a group by.

So you need to add `GROUP BY code,model` to the end as those columns are in the select but they aren't in a aggregate function

This won't give you what you're after though.

Here's one way to get what you're after:

```
SELECT * FROM Printer WHERE color='y'
AND price = (
  SELECT min(price) 
  FROM printer where color='y'
  );
```

You could also do this with windowing functions but I don't know if they are supported by postgresql

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting but fine, as long as it is correct, you're enriching the internet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can `INNER JOIN` the `printers` table to a subquery table containing the minimum price whose record(s) you want to display.

```
SELECT p1.code, p1.model, p1.price
FROM printer p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(price) AS minPrice
    FROM printer
    WHERE color='y'
) p2
ON p1.price = p2.minPrice
WHERE p1.color='y'
```

Comment: Sorry.  Put `WHERE` before `GROUP BY`

Comment: This won't actually work; since `code` is unique, you'll end up with the "minimum price" for every printer.

Comment: Facepalm.  He just wants the absolute `MIN`.

Comment: You probably want to include the colour filter there also.

Comment: Better yet, include it in the `ON` clause.

Comment: ... if it is contained in the subquery... which it is not

Comment: "temporary table" is a specific term for a feature that exists within [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html), and what you're showing isn't one of them. What you're showing is a subquery.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see the light now, and now I'm a true believer.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` groups the columns provided to it and helps in aggregation. For example:

```
select customer_name, count(*), sum(product_price)
from orders
group by customer_name
```

This will group all the product names something like this:

```
customer_name  price
cust1         10 -- bought product1 for $10
cust1         10 -- bought product1 for $10 again
cust1         20 -- bought product2 for $20
cust2          5
cust2          1
```

Then it takes cust1 and counts how many products appeared (3 products) and total of the price (10+10+20 = 40). Then it takes cust2 and does the same thing giving the result:

```
cust1  3  40
cust2  2   6
```

If grouping was done by customer and year, it could look like this:

```
select customer_name, year(order_date), count(*), sum(price)
from orders
group by customer_name, year(order_date);
```

Notice that fields that are not aggregated are grouped (e.g. customer_name and year(order_date)).